# laravel query for delete where date < now() with INTERVAL N days

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a laravel project now I stuck on a query. I want to use this query:

```
DELETE FROM on_search WHERE search_date < NOW() - INTERVAL N DAY
```

but cant converted into laravel like DB::table('table_name)->where(......)-> _____ ;

Answer (score 1):

```
$days = 10;

DB::table('on_search')
    ->whereRaw('search_date < NOW() - INTERVAL ? DAY', [$days])
    ->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do date manipulation in php with the Carbon class.

```
// Top of file.
use Carbon\Carbon;

DB::table('table_name)->where('search_date', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay(10));
```